# Material Theme for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, material-design, themes, visual-studio-2019

For the last years, I have used Solarized Dark and VS Color Theme Editor themes in Visual Studio 2017 and after trying [Material Theme](https://material-theme.site/) in Visual Studio Code, I wanted to use this wonderful theme in Visual Studio 2019 as well. However, there is no compatible version of Material Theme for VS2019 unfortunately. I am wondering if there is a possibility to transform this theme i.e. with the help of an export tool as Extension Manager mentioned on [Use your favorite extensions with Visual Studio 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/use-your-favorite-extensions-with-visual-studio-2019/). Or is there any theme available similar to Material Theme for Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install the [Color Themes for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ColorThemesforVisualStudio) extension, from Microsoft DevLabs.

As of the date of this post, the extension includes a Material Dark theme, among others (refer to the [GiHub Repository](https://github.com/microsoft/VS-ColorThemes/tree/master/VSColorThemes/Themes) for more information).

NOTE: You can also customise an existing theme, using the Color Theme Editor, for [VS 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor) and [VS 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2019ColorThemeEditor).

Comment: Where we can put the xml files directly which is mentioned in the [Github Repository](https://github.com/microsoft/VS-ColorThemes/tree/master/VSColorThemes/Themes)

Answer (score 11):

Check out the colour themes from Dainty for Visual Studio.

https://dainty.site/vs

You will need Node and Yarn installed to build the theme(s) you want.  Not all the themes work perfectly with VS2019 but they do have a couple of Material Themes.

Comment: These look great. I wonder why he makes his themes for Visual Studio Code available via the VS Marketplace, but not those for Visual Studio? Any idea?

Comment: The dainty is no longer maintained see [GitHub Project](https://github.com/dainty-color-theme-generator/dainty-vs)

Comment: @Max link is broken, user is gone.